# No access to debug in Xcode 4

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, debugging

I create c++ console application in Xcode 4 and build it. App works normally, but when I try to debug, I can't use any button in Product/Debug/

[image]

I tried with c++, iOS, object-c projects and I always see this window.
But if I use breakpoints I can stop running, but still can't use steps.
Any suggestions??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Xcode 4, you need to enable breakpoints, which enables Debugging, and then run your app. To do this, toggle the button beside the run (play) button (looks like a sideways bookmark), or use Command-Y, as seen in your screenshot.